# ¿Hay un modismo equivalente a "with a grain of salt" en español?

Tags: expresiones, solicitud-de-modismo

"With a grain of salt" es un modismo que quiere decir que algo debe tomarse con cierto escepticismo o distancia del asunto. Quizá incluso un poco *a la ligera*.

> "(With) a grain of salt", (or "a pinch of salt") is an idiom of the English language, which means to view something with skepticism or not to interpret something literally
>
> <sub>[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grain_of_salt)</sub>

En español se usa a veces el *latinismo* **cum grano salis** con el mismo significado

> La locución latina cum grano salis traducida literalmente significa "con un grano de sal" y figuradamente parece significar que uno debe aplicar una capa de **sano escepticismo** a una determinada afirmación y **no darla por certeza absoluta** sin haberla contrastado antes debidamente.
>
> <sub>[Más wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cum_grano_salis)</sub>

Pero indica también esta entrada que

> Por otro lado, en otras lenguas europeas, como en alemán, la locución ["cum grano salis"] se utiliza en ese **sentido escéptico e irónico**, mientras en español, según el DRAE,​ "[con su grano de sal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JTLT03z)" significaría: "Dicho de tratarse y gobernarse, especialmente un punto arduo y delicado: Con prudencia, madurez y reflexión."
>
> Quizá en esta diferencia pesen los usos gastronómicos ("una pizca de sal", "no pasarse con la sal") y por los que tomara en España el significado de "con moderación". Pero éste no es, sin embargo, el significado que se desprende de la cita [original de Plinio "cum grano salis"].

Viendo entonces que la traducción literal significa `Con prudencia, madurez y reflexión`, ¿qué otros modismos hay en español que tengan el significado de "with a grain of salt" / "cum grano salis"? Es decir, "tomar una cierta afirmación con cierto escepticismo y prudencia".

Answer (score 10):

A pesar de que no aparece en el DLE, con el sentido de "tomar una cierta afirmación con cierto escepticismo y prudencia" tenemos en español la expresión:

> **Coger/tomar algo con pinzas**

Se desprende del hecho de tener que sujetar con pinzas algo que se quiere examinar para poder observarlo mejor (al microscopio, con una lupa, etc.), o algo que no se quiere tocar con las manos.

He aquí un uso **literal** de la expresión:

> *[...] hasta que llegaron a ser tan minúsculos esos objetos y esas ropas, Madre Benita, que hay que tomarlas con pinzas y mirarlas con lupa para apreciar la suntuosidad maniática de sus detalles.*
>
> José Donoso, "El obsceno pájaro de la noche", 1970 (Chile).

Y aquí un uso **figurado**:

> *Don Julio, como un Lapidario medioeval, había de coger cada palabra, como con pinzas, y no admitirla y ponerla en circulación, hasta llegar a la convicción absoluta de que esa palabra —cada palabra— era entendida exactamente igual en Madrid, que en Buenos Aires, Caracas, Méjico.*
>
> José María Pemán, "Mis almuerzos con gente importante", 1970 (España).

Y un ejemplo más reciente que ya omite el uso de *como* para indicar la comparación:

> *Semejanza (sema común, al menos) y sustitución coinciden con las nociones clásicas en que Aristóteles sustenta la metáfora -traslación y analogía-, si bien de sus propias palabras podemos advertir que la noción de semejanza o analogía debe cogerse con pinzas: [...].*
>
> Alberto Carrere, José Saborit, "Retórica de la pintura", 2000 (España).

Y la versión más usada en Hispanoamérica:

> *Por aquella época empezaría a cuestionar un montón de insensateces que son moneda corriente de nuestra sociedad, o dicho de otra manera, tomaba con pinzas las opiniones unánimemente aceptadas.*
>
> Rodolfo Bojorge, "La aventura submarina. Equipo, técnicas y experiencias", 1992 (Argentina).